# MongoDB: How to set timestamp during insertOne() without using new Date() for insertOne() like NOW() in PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

`time: { $currentDate: { $type: "timestamp" } } });`

**It's not working for insert()**

can you help me, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

The `$currentDate` is an [update operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/#-currentdate) so you will need to use one of the MongoDB [Date() and Datetime](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Date/) methods. Here is an example a few you can choose:

```js
db.collection.insertOne(
    {  
        name: "bob",
        age: 20,
        time: ISODate(), // ISODate("2024-02-01T08:00:30.429Z"),
        time2: new Date(), // ISODate("2024-02-01T08:00:30.429Z"),
        time3: new Timestamp() // Timestamp({ t: 1706774430, i: 1 })
    }
);
```

See [HERE](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/KJDg3ze8o1v) for a full working example.

Comment: But new Date() based device settings right i need mongodb server time. like now() in postgresql

Comment: @VinayKumar yes that is correct. The result of `ISODate()` or `new Date()` for example is assigned as the value to that property of the document which is then sent along as a parameter to the `insertOne` method. You would need to use an update with `$currentDate` like in [this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/#example) to get actual server time or with an aggregation using the [NOW](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#mongodb-variable-variable.NOW) System Variable.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a document with only a few fields, you could do an *upsert* with the `$currentDate` operator so that the timestamp is determined at the MongoDB server:

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: "123"
},
{
  $setOnInsert: {
    anotherField: 123
  },
  $currentDate: {
    timestamp: true
  }
},
{
  upsert: true
})
```

It is important not to match another document with the filter (first parameter); otherwise, this document would receive a new timestamp and no new document would be created.

See this [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KuHiZczKl_C).